# Get row count on previous Codeigniter AR query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I'm writing a web app, with Codeigniter, that allows a user to enter query parameters and then spits out the results.

For pagination, I'm passing a limit and offset (pretty standard stuff) and can return results based on that, however, I'm having trouble passing back the TOTAL number or records that would have been returned without using the LIMIT and OFFSET parameters.

My question:  Is it possible to pass the total row count that would have been returned by a previous query using Codeigniters AR syntax?

I've tried a few variations of the below, but have (at best) been able to return a count of ALL records in the items table (using count_all_results).  I feel like I'm missing something here.

```
if (isset($brand)) {$this->db->where('brand', $brand);}
if (isset($color)) {$this->db->where('color', $color);}
$items = $this->db->get('items', $page, $offset)->result_array();
$rowcount = $this->db->count_all_results('items);    
return array('items' => $items, 'row_count' => $rowcount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

```
if (isset($brand)) {$this->db->where('brand', $brand);}
if (isset($color)) {$this->db->where('color', $color);}

$query = $this->db->get('items', $page, $offset);
$items = $query->result_array();
$rowcount = $query->num_rows();

return array('items' => $items, 'row_count' => $rowcount);
```

Comment: Thanks Vlakarados.  This works, except the max it will ever return is the $page count (the LIMIT).  In my case it's 6.  I need to get the total so I can pass it to the pagination config ($config['total_rows']).  Do I need to set up and run the query twice (once w/o the limit/offset and once with)?

Comment: Yes, for that you should run the second query, unless you will make a MySQL sub-query, but that would be pretty complicated to use, so the best way is to do 2 queries.

Comment: Thanks Vlak - 2 queries worked.  Seems like extra steps, but I guess there is no other way.  Will put the final code in the orig. post but credit goes to you for the answer.

Comment: No problem, but I suggest you to remove that `if` statement and make it 2 separate methods, that would be more MVC style and easier to use than using extra arguments to your method. It's not necessary though, but is considered to be good practice.